# How can I call the position of a group of selected vertices in maxscript?

Tags: maxscript

I am in the midst of creating a GUI that will create a spline along a premade hose tube. The purpose of this is to simulate moving hoses in a hydraulic powered machine rig. This script is meant to make it more efficient to create the lines instead of having to manually position them within the 3 default viewports.

What I am asking is how I can be able to call upon the value shown within the view window after I have selected a group of vertices. Here is an example of what I mean:

[image: Example]

My goal is to take the average value of all selected vertices and place them within a list, and I would continue to select these vertices along the length of the hose. Eventually I will have a full list of vertex point values, and I will create a spline that matches those position values, allowing me to deform them with the bezier tool after it has been created. I am just wondering how to call the values within the red circle into a value in maxscript and use it within my GUI. If I have not made myself clear enough, please comment so. Thank you for any and all advice!

Answer (score 2):

If your mesh is collapsed to editable Mesh or editable Poly, you can use this method:

```
fn averageSelVertPosition obj =
(
    verts = obj.selectedVerts
    p = Point3 0 0 0
    for v in verts do
    (
        p += v.pos
    )
    p = p/verts.count
    return p
)
```

It will return a Point3 value of the average position of the selected vertices of the specified node.

If you are using and edit_poly modifier, you probably need to use polyops. You can reed about 'em here: http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/16/ENU/MAXScript-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-B40F84EA-5F19-45B6-AA7C-0ADC77708BBE.htm,topicNumber=d30e394721

The method would be the same.

1. Retrieve all vertices
2. Average their positions by:

   2.a:  Adding their positions (Point3) together and

   2.b:  dividing by number of vertices.

-

Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: he is correct. you take the positions of each vertex, add them all together, then divide by the number of vertices selected. this will result in the average position.

or you can calculate the center point of the selected vertices bounding box. I use this method often.